# Function local static function-object that's initialized by lambda, thread-safe or not?

Tags: c++, static, lambda, c++11, thread-safety

Is the following function thread-safe? And if it's not thread-safe, then is there really any overhead in making that funImpl non-static? Or does the compiler actually inline that function-object function and skip creating the function object altogether?

```
int myfun(std::array<int, 10> values)
{
    static const auto funImpl = [&]() -> int
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            sum += values[i];
        }
        return sum;
    };

    return funImpl();
}
```

EDIT:
I edited the function signature from:

```
int myfun(const std::array<int, 10>& values)
```

to:

```
int myfun(std::array<int, 10> values)
```

so that it is clear that I'm not asking about the tread-safety of values, but the thread-safety of the function local static variable funImpl.

Comment: Is there some reason to use this instead of `std::accumulate`?

Comment: Obviously there's no reason to ever use that code. It exists only to enable me to ask my question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Might this version be faster than `std::accumulate` on some implementations, if `std::accumulate` is using iterators?  And supposing that 10 is just for the purposes of the example and could be something much larger.

Comment: @MattPhillips: I suppose it might be faster, but given that it doesn't do the right thing, I doubt it matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not only is it not thread safe, it doesn't do what you want.

By defining the lambda as static, it captures (by reference) the array passed in the first time it's called.  Further calls continue to reference the original array, regardless of which array is passed in.

When the first array goes out of scope, further calls will invoke UB, as it now has a dangling reference.

Edit: An example http://ideone.com/KCcav

Note, even if you captured by value, you'd still have a problem because it would still only capture the first time you invoke the function.  You wouldn't have the dangling pointer, but it still would only initialize the copy the first time.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't know this.